# Radio Lab - A well and interestingly produced internet chat show

Tags: radio

Hey everyone,

Just thought I'd share my most recent discovery:
www.radiolab.org

It's a chat show that covers many topics, mostly highly unusual, but nicely produced and put together from a sound perspective!

Enjoy!

Comment: @Andre, thanks for sharing! I love stuff like that.

Comment: @Jay, sure thing, enjoy

Comment: +1 for Radiolab! Very entertaining, informative and well-produced, I listen to it in the car.

Comment: been a listener for 2 years now...great sound design and great reporting.

Comment: @Jay @EMV @Andre @Kurt Wow! What mics do they use on the hosts and guests? The mix of the voices sounds great! Anyone know how and where they record these?

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But latest show i didnt understand in some places. Dialogs were layering over the ambiances taken from the streets... surrealism talk show...

Comment: I like it! Have been listening to it all afternoon :) Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: Thanks! It's fantastic, I'm hooked, I'm addicted, I'm listening to it every day on my bike on my way to work...

Answer (score 1):

I love RadioLab, they have the philosophy that great stories can be given to you by sound design and fun story telling. Anyone wanting to do sound design for radio/podcasts/plays, etc. should have a listen. Plus the content is great as a bonus.